# What are the white and black spots on the under side of my chilli leaves?

Tags: diseases, plant-care, chili

I am a newbie to gardening and was so chuffed to see my chilli (the plants are Chile guajilo and Chile chipotle) plants grow up. However, I have noticed leaves starting to fall. These leaves have, on the underside, black and white dots. They look like a central black dot with surrounding white clouds. How do I get rid of it? Is it going to kill my chilli plant?

What are some helpful suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered scale insects? Or mealy bugs?

Comment: Thank you. Looks like mealy bugs from google search. Fingers crossed  that neem oil spray and isopropyl alcohol will do the job.

Comment: Try to wipe it off with a wet towel